# What does the phrase "move back up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "move back up" in the following text from the description of the game aiko no Tatsujin Pop Tap Beat:

> If you are stuck on one particularly tricky section, lower the
> difficulty level to try it with fewer notes. Once you master that,
> **move back up**.

Here is a description of the game from a different source (Apple App Store) :

> Sync to the rhythm and drum away to those notes!
>
> The traditional Japanese drumming rhythm game, Taiko no Tatsujin,
> comes to Apple Arcade.
>
> Sync to the rhythm and drum away to those notes!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Move back up" can have an idiomatic meaning, but in the context of your example, it should be taken at face value. "Back" can mean *to return to something or somewhere you have previously been*. The text says that you should "lower the difficulty level" if you are stuck, and then, having mastered it, "*move back up*" meaning return to the higher level (hence 'up') that you were previously at.

Answer (score 14):

"Move back up" here means to return to the higher level.

Your sentence says that if you are having a hard time with a section, lower the difficulty until you feel comfortable with it, then increase the difficulty to the original level.

So, go down in difficulty, then go back up to the original difficulty.